# control babel polyfill method's location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a JSX component written in AMD

inside the component I have:

```
<div className="survey" { ...this.props }>
```

Babel will transform it to

```
React.createElement(
        'div',
        _extends({ className: 'survey'
        }, this.props)
```

and a polyfill method will be added at the top of the file, so I will have

```
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };
define('Display', [''], function () {
  var Display = React.createClass({
```

is there any way to force Babel to place this method inside my module definition (within define) ?

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: I don't want to have _extends in the global namespace

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/external-helpers/ seems able to solve this issue for me